# How to hide page title from WooCommerce Storefront theme homepage?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am trying to hide the Storefront page title on my homepage. This code hides it from all the side:

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
    remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

But I can't use is_front_page() because WordPress loads functions.php before the $wp_query object has been set up with the current page, as explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41805/is-front-page-only-works-in-theme-file-and-does-not-work-in-functions-php).

I would prefer not using the plugin "Title Toggle for Storefront Theme".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace "init" with "wp":

```
add_action( 'wp', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't understand right the answer you linked to. You can't use `is_front_page()` right inside *functions.php*, but you can totally use it in a callback function.

> The `is_front_page()` conditional is only available after the query is setup, which happens at **init**.

So this:

```
function sf_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
    if(is_front_page()) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'sf_change_homepage_title' );
```

Will work.

Comment: I tried that before posting this question but it doesn't work.

Comment: If it doesn't work it's because your `storefront_page` action is executed before `init`. Considering this action is related to your theme/plugin, you have to find out at what point it is register and what hook you can use to take action before. Maybe try out with `after_setup_theme` instead of `init`.