# Remove page title from woocommerce storefront theme homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

this has been asked before and I have tried the numerous solutions here, but none are working for me. I have set the homepage to a static page using the woocommerce storefront homepage template, and would like to remove the page title header. I have tried adding this code to my functions.php but it did nothing,

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
   remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header' );
}
```

I have tried the folowing answers:

[How to hide page title from WooCommerce Storefront theme homepage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696549/how-to-hide-page-title-from-woocommerce-storefront-theme-homepage)

&

[WooCommerce StoreFront child theme - How to remove title on homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770814/woocommerce-storefront-child-theme-how-to-remove-title-on-homepage)

The below code worked, but only for the shop page. I could not find a conditional tag for the homepage.

```
function wc_hide_page_title()
{
    if( !is_shop() ) // is_shop is the conditional tag
        return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title' );
```

Can anyone help me doing this without using a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the storefront homepage template then you need to use the storefront_homepage action.

```
function wc_hide_page_title() {
    if( is_front_page() ) 
    remove_action( 'storefront_homepage', 'storefront_homepage_header', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function wc_hide_page_title() {
    if( is_front_page() ) 
        return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to **hide the Page Title** on the Homepage or from any specific page.

```
function wc_hide_page_title()
{
    if( !is_page('home') ) // is_page is the conditional tag. 'home' is the page slug or use ID of the page instead of page slug.
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked at time of posting:

```
function jasom_dotnet_change_homepage_title( $args ) {
    if(is_front_page()) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_page', 'storefront_page_header', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'jasom_dotnet_change_homepage_title' );
```